# How to remove white border from image

Tags: java

[image]

I want to remove edges from this image. I am interested in removing border from this picture. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: We aren't here to do your homework. What have you tried?

Comment: If your requirement is for that picture only, then use MS Paint or use Photoshop.

Comment: I want to get some idea from u people. I have tried Roberts algorithm but it is not helping me.

Comment: Any link to "Roberts Algorithm"? Do youmean Robert Sedgewick? What exact problem do you have? Loading the image, decompression, navigating the bytes? Any help can only come with more info on the problem.

Comment: @wmorrison365 http://www.inf.ufpr.br/danielw/pos/ci724/20102/HIPR2/flatjavasrc/Roberts.java
I have tried this algorithm. I have performed histogram equalization on original image and after that i have performed edge detection on it and after that I've got the attached image. Now I want to remove the white circular border of this image.

Answer (score 1):

not really an answer but i can lead you towards the right direction
I dont know whether this is a small or big requirement for you , but doing this in java requires some research area .
I think you have to study DIGITAL IMAGE PROCESSING IN JAVA
this [link][1]

[1]: http://www.imagingbook.com/ might be helpful

the possible solution which i tried once and worked up to some limit for me
step 1 : create bufferedImage from your current image
step 2 : iterate the image buffer matrix pixel by pixel
step 3 : apply any edge detection algorithm
step 4 : after having detected the edge , replace the color pixels from the pixels existing inside the border shape

to apply this edge detection java has some inbuilt library for "**Gaussian filter**" and some more filters like that

, if this is any sort of help to you , then i will be posting some more of my work , let me know if you need any explanation .

Comment: I have performed histogram equalization on original image and after that i have performed edge detection on it and after that I've got the attached image. Now I want to remove the white circular border of this image.

Comment: ohk , since you are are on the right track , and i also have done also similar level of work , so cant be promising any further in my comment , but i'll try to figure something out for you and will let you know

Comment: I want to make it asap. So quick help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: @Prasad Pofali: FYI: Have you seen this post? [how to remove a border with an unknown width from an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253739/how-to-remove-a-border-with-an-unknown-width-from-an-image?rq=1)

Comment: @wmorrison365 yep i hv seen this post bt it is dealing only with removal of square border and not with circular border.

Comment: @Prasad Pofali - Ok. This is the sort of information you should put in your original question though. I did edit the question yesterday to furnish it with the extra info you provided me with. However my edit apparently needed to be peer-reviewed and has not been included so far for some reason. I suggest you add these extra titbits that you've put as individual comments into the original question. That would probably have prevented it being closed.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me on this topic. I have solved this problem with some functions provided by "Java". So my problem is solved.